# How to add a Google account in Android wear 2.0 Emulator?

Tags: android, wear-os

I need to add a Google account to view the on-watch Play Store in the emulator.

[image: Add Google account prompt]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you [set up a phone](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/downloads.html#set_up_a_phone) and [set up an emulator](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/downloads.html#set_up_an_emulator), you may then pair the phone with the emulator and sync a Google Account using the following steps:

1. Follow the steps for setting up a phone.
2. On the phone, enable Developer Options and USB Debugging.
3. Connect the phone to your computer through USB.
4. Forward the AVD's communication port to the connected handheld device (each time the phone is connected):

   `adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601`
5. On the phone, in the Android Wear app, begin the standard pairing process. For example, on the Welcome screen, tap the **Set It Up** button. Alternatively, if an existing watch already is paired, in the upper-left drop-down, tap **Add a New Watch**.
6. On the phone, in the Android Wear app, tap the Overflow button, and then tap **Pair with Emulator**.
7. Tap the Settings icon.
8. Under Device Settings, tap **Emulator**.
9. Tap **Accounts** and select a Google Account, and follow the steps in the wizard to sync the account with the emulator. If necessary, type the screen-lock device password, and Google Account password, to start the account sync.

For more information, see [Download and Test with a Device](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/downloads.html)

Comment: Does this procedure work if the Android Wear app is running on iOS?

Comment: @Teyam is it possible to bind two emulators like that? Do in need to forward  remote->local and then the same_local->other_remote ?